# How to print esc characters as characters in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, special-characters, ansi-escape

There is a Delphi string #10#13#09. If I print it as a normal string I see result of special chars printing, i.e. carriage return and tab indent. I need to see "◙♪○" like Far Manager does. How to make it in Delphi? 
chr(), ansichar() are not helped

Comment: Print it "to what"? Also, show your code.

Comment: Are you assuming that some canonical representation of UNPRINTABLE characters exists? It doesn't. You write it yourself.  What representation do you want to see? Do you know what Far Manager does? If you don't, then how do you expect to write code that does what it does.  A typical way of handling this is to write a function that detects if a string contains unprintable characters and translating them into some format that you find more readable. For example, "{cr}" for carriage return or Delphi Literals like #10 #13.  The latter is quite easy to write.

Answer (score 2):

Use proper fonts (I know about `Terminal`):

```
var
  i: Integer;
  s: string;
begin
  Canvas.Font.Name := 'Terminal';
  for i := 1 to 31 do begin
    s := Char(i);
    Canvas.TextOut(10, 18 * i, s);
  end;
```